# Rails 5 beta 3 ActiveRecord Record Invalid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've created a rather large script to seed my rails database.  It's a one to many relationship using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` to help build the parameter hash.  The script worked fine for several days, but now I get the following error.

> ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Website statistics websites must exist

I've disabled strong parameters because this is a read only application.  All records are imported from seeds.rb so there is no create, new, edit method in my controller
Here's my hash and array of hashes.

```
{:company=>"Company A", :link=>"www.whatever.com",    
 `:website_statistics_attributes=>`
    [{:statistic=>"Visitors", :today=>10, :this_week=>11.4, :last_week=>13.0},
     {:statistic=>"Page Views", :today=>20,   :this_week=>55, :last_week=>120}]}
```

The only thing that did change is; I cloned a version of this from github. I pushed my production version to github, then cloned onto my macbook.  The setup is identical so i'm not sure what's going on here.

EDIT: Models

```
class WebsiteStatistic < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :websites
end

class Website < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :website_statistics 
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :website_statistics
end
```

Comment: Is it possible the validation is failing for your associated `website_statistics` model?

Comment: show both models definitions

Answer (score 0):

Ok..... Here's what fixed it.

Supposedly in Rails 5 you can run either `rake` or `rails` to perform `db:` operations.  For some reason when you do `rake db:seed` it throws the error above.  However if you do `rails db:seed` it works.

using `rake db:drop`, `rake db:create`, or `rake db:migrate` WORKS

using `rake db:seed`, `rake db:reset`, or `rake db:setup` FAILS